# GoogleAuthException: Unknown with Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have added an API to an existing GAE application. 
API is intended to be used through an Android application with Google Cloud Endpoints and OAuth2 authentication.

When I access the API without authentication everything works fine, but with authentication the following error occurs.
Everything also works fine when testing through API Explorer with OAuth2 enabled.

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:255)
at com.appspot.p2ptransfers.MainActivity$2.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:248)
at com.appspot.p2ptransfers.MainActivity$2.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:234)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Error can be reproduced with

```
try {
  _Credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(MainActivity.this,"server:client_id:" + Utilities.WEB_CLIENT_ID);
  _Credential.setSelectedAccountName("valid_email@gmail.com");
  _Credential.getToken();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
  String s = Log.getStackTraceString(e);
  Log.e("Endpoints", s);
}
```

API is defined as

```
WEB_CLIENT_ID = '<WEB_CLIENT_ID>'
ANDROID_CLIENT_ID = '<ANDROID_CLIENT_ID>'
ANDROID_AUDIENCE = WEB_CLIENT_ID

@endpoints.api(name='<api name>', version='v1',
           allowed_client_ids=[WEB_CLIENT_ID, ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID],
           audiences=[WEB_CLIENT_ID],
           scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE])
```

Both Client IDs where generated through API Console.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted the problem when I was playing with [Google OAuth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). 
The error I received was

```
Error: invalid_client
The OAuth client was deleted.
```

And then I remembered that a month ago I have mistakenly deleted the project, but then I undeleted it in a few minutes.

When I created a new project and generated new client ids, everything started working.